# Can't get golang working on Fedora 19

Tags: software-installation, bashrc

I've installed the `golang` package on Fedora 19.

Go also needs the the `GOPATH` variable. I added to my `~/.bashrc`:

```
GOPATH=$HOME/.go/
```

But `go env` didn't see it (after the `source ~/.bashrc`):

```
GOARCH="386"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="8"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="386"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib/golang"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/golang/pkg/tool/linux_386"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m32 -pthread"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Why it didn't see my `GOPATH`?

PS: `echo $GOPATH`:

```
/home/m0nhawk/.go/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need to export the variable for it to be visible to `go env`:

```
export GOPATH="$HOME/.go"
```

should work.